# how should i have a javascript animation execute when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, animation, transition

I dont want to use css3 transition, keeping it pure .js. let assume the following [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein)

when you click, div(s) appear, but how can i get the same function run when the page load/open rather than triggering the function by clicking on btn.??

Comment: Do you want vanilla.js or jQuery? Also, jQuery transitions actually change the CSS of DOM elements. I'm not sure there's a feasible way to have transitions without using CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, they were showing it to you in jQuery, and they were already wrapping it in a function that is not executed until the page is loaded.  You just need to remove the "guts" of the click handler and call it directly.

Change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeIn();
        $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
    });
});
```

To:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#div1").fadeIn();
     $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
     $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Comment: Hi, i got another question, now imagine we have div with the same properties but it at the very bottom of the page where the user has to scroll down to see. how should make it animate (like it does now) only when the user scroll down. in other word how should i make it animate on user scroll??  please check this template and scroll down and see how div appears as you scroll:

Answer (score -1):

Trigger the event on pageload or what jquery calls it, `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // do whatever.
});
```

`document.ready` short version

```
 $(function () {
   // do whatever.
 });
```